# yAxis cut off in Shinobi iOS Chart

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, shinobi

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fqez61k9jhnoa4/Screen%20Shot%202017-06-01%20at%201.04.25%20PM.png?dl=0

- (void)createBurnoutChart {

  //Create the chart (if needed)
  if (burnoutChart == nil) {
      if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

  ```
       burnoutChart = [[ShinobiChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 270, 768,725)];  // iPad
  else

      burnoutChart = [[ShinobiChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 165, 320,290)];  // iPhone

  // Set a different theme on the chart
  SChartMidnightTheme *midnight = [[SChartMidnightTheme alloc] init];
  [burnoutChart setTheme:midnight];

  //As the chart is a UIView, set its resizing mask to allow it to automatically resize when screen orientation changes.
  burnoutChart.autoresizingMask = ~UIViewAutoresizingNone;

  // Initialise the data source we will use for the chart
  burnoutDatasource = [[LineChartDataSource alloc] initWithFileName:LineChartSource_Burnout seriesCount:1];

  // Give the chart the data source
  burnoutChart.datasource = burnoutDatasource;

  // Create a date time axis to use as the x axis.
  SChartDateTimeAxis *xAxis = [[SChartDateTimeAxis alloc] init];

  // Enable panning and zooming on the x-axis.
  xAxis.enableGesturePanning = YES;
  xAxis.enableGestureZooming = YES;
  xAxis.enableMomentumPanning = YES;
  xAxis.enableMomentumZooming = YES;
  xAxis.axisPositionValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];

  // And allow them to scroll past the default range
  xAxis.allowPanningOutOfMaxRange = YES;
  xAxis.allowPanningOutOfDefaultRange = YES;

  // Make the frequency of tick marks be one day
  SChartDateFrequency *freq = [[SChartDateFrequency alloc] initWithDay:1];
  xAxis.majorTickFrequency = freq;

  burnoutChart.xAxis = xAxis;

  //Create a number axis to use as the y axis.
  //TODO:Checkback
  NSNumber *lowRange = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];
  NSNumber *highRange = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:100];

  SChartNumberRange *yRange = [[SChartNumberRange alloc] initWithMinimum:lowRange andMaximum:highRange];
  SChartNumberAxis *yAxis = [[SChartNumberAxis alloc] initWithRange:yRange ];

  //Enable panning and zooming on Y
  yAxis.enableGesturePanning = YES;
  yAxis.enableGestureZooming = YES;
  yAxis.enableMomentumPanning = YES;
  yAxis.enableMomentumZooming = YES;
  ```

  //        yAxis.axisPositionValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];

  ```
  // And allow them to scroll past the default range
  yAxis.allowPanningOutOfMaxRange = NO;
  yAxis.allowPanningOutOfDefaultRange = NO;


  burnoutChart.yAxis.defaultRange;
  burnoutChart.yAxis = yAxis;

  //Set the chart title
  burnoutChart.title = @"";
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
      burnoutChart.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:27.0f];
  } else {
      burnoutChart.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:17.0f];
  }
  burnoutChart.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


  // If you have a trial version, you need to enter your licence key here:
  //    chart.licenseKey = @"";

  // Add the chart to the view controller
  [self.viewBurnoutChart addSubview:burnoutChart];
  ```

  }

  // Make sure we get the latest data
  NSInteger lastScore = [burnoutDatasource reReadData];
  [self vasBurnoutImage:lastScore];
  [self vasBurnoutScore:lastScore];
  [burnoutChart reloadData];
  [burnoutChart redrawChartAndGL:YES];

  //***** Important for resetting visible portion..if I ever get it towork
  //[burnoutChart.xAxis resetZoomLevel];
  }

The chart displays well but when it comes to the yAxis it stops exactly at the 100 limit range. I want to show more intervals so that it doesn't look like it was cut off.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this:

- If you want to manually set the range for the axis (as you do currently), then simply increase the range e.g. to 103. The tick labels should not be affected.
- If you're happy to let the chart determine the range then you can use the `rangePaddingHigh` property to adjust how much padding is added to the calculated range.

I hope that helps!